# What would one call the difference between lap times?

Tags: time, sports

Let's say I ran a 200m. And my lap times would be: 14.50 seconds on the first 100m and 13.70 seconds in the last 100m.

What would one call the difference between those two lap times (0.80 seconds).

In Dutch we have a name for it: *verval* (literal: *decay* or *decline*). I was wondering if the English language has one.

---

**Update:**

*@AndyT* answered: **Delta**. This is used in Formula 1, Mathemetics and Physics. Can someone substantiate this? Note: *I am looking for a term that is commonly used in sports*.

Comment: What is the Dutch word (and its literal translation)? Does it include the direction of the change (in this case faster)? *Negative splits*might fit, but that normally refers to longer runs. [This guide](https://greatist.com/fitness/ultimate-guide-running-lingo) to running terminology might be of interest.

Comment: The Dutch word is "verval". The literal translation would be decay or decline. But you can have a negative or positive 'verval'. In my question it would be negative, since the second lap time is slower than the first one.

Comment: How would simple "difference" not fit your need, please?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin because in Dutch the term "difference" (Dutch: "verschil") and "whatever the commonly used term for the difference between lap/split times in sports is" (Dutch: "verval") are different. And I was wondering if the English language has a term for this. But I guess it's not very well known.

Comment: An English "lap…" and its "time”… is once round the track. You might transpose that to once along the 200m course; not at all the same as splitting 200m into twice 100m. 

Who would allow anyone to run 100m and double his time?

Why are you not asking Dutch scholars who follow how the term "difference" (Dutch: "verschil") and "whatever the commonly used term for the difference between lap/split times in sports is" (Dutch: "verval") are different?

Are you saying Dutch speakers accept “whatever the commonly used term for the difference between lap/split times in sports is” as an idiom?

Comment: Whatever else, how did "delta" creep into this? "Delta v" is used in maths and physics - I don't follow F1 - to mean "change in velocity" and that's so far from being the same thing as "different time", you might as well say they had nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin in Dutch we use a lot of English terms within our own language. Not even half of these words official, but we use them when speaking anyways. I don't know if there's an English verb for using WhatsApp, but in Dutch we recently created a verb for it. In Dutch we create verbs and new words every year. Our tiny country has a strong focus on internationalization in our education. So I think my answer here is: yes, we accept a lot of terms. Especially when speaking! We only care about our authentic language when writing essays or columns for newspapers, for example.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin ^ This is also the reason why there are a lot of grammar erros in our news papers (for example). And I don't think this is a good thing for our language! But it's just the way it is. We accept and allow a lot. There are quite a lot of Dutch studies about this actually. If you have a better word for my question here. I'd love to discuss this in a private conversation!

Comment: Derk, the point is not whether I have, but that almost certainly no-one has any word in English that comes close to what you're talking about. I don't claim to know, and I do suspect no-one will give you any candidate word. English just doesn't work like that… and I suspect you'll find no Germanic language does and that's not the point.

I very much doubt Dutch allows what you're describing, any more than any other language.

Please deal with my earlier comments about lap times before insisting this is about English, Dutch or any other language, rather than your own vocabulary.

Answer (score 2):

In Formula 1 this would be referred to as a **∆** (pronounced **delta**).

In science/engineering in general delta (the fourth letter of the greek alphabet) is used to denote changes or differences (ref: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_(letter)#Upper_case)). For example ∆v is the change in velocity (ref: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-v)).

In Formula 1 "delta" is used for the difference in lap time, most often the difference in lap time *up to the current point in the lap*. Often when talking about their fastest lap drivers will say something along the lines of:

> I came round the 9th corner, checked the delta on my steering wheel, and saw I was massively up on my previous fastest

Comment: Could you supply a reference to this. I have never heard of it before and I have a science background.

Comment: @NigelJ - The best reference I found (for the science/engineering bit) was [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/delta?s=t) definition 5: "*Mathematics*. an incremental change in a variable". I remember from A-level maths and physics and my engineering degree that you'd talk about e.g. "delta-v" for change in velocity, but I have no reference for that. Note that the greek upper case letter would be used, rather than the word "delta", but I don't know how to write that on here.

Comment: The cursive delta - δ - is commomly used in calculus for the rate of change, but I think you need a reference to support using the uncial form of delta - Δ - to describe differences in value.

Comment: @NigelJ - Fair enough. A bit of digging in the right place (specifically: googling "delta v") and I've found a better reference. Answer edited.

Comment: This sounds familiar! There's a part of teaching material in Mathematics and Physics: _Differentiating_. In this case, Delta is the value of acceleration or deceleration!

Comment: I’m no scientist and I’m familiar with delta representing change. (I am a computer programmer though.)

Answer (score 0):

I heard the term 'splits' used but I am not sure if that is the difference between competitors?

Comment: I think that splits are the same as laps. But I'm not so sure as well...

Comment: I too heard the terms 'negative split' and 'positive split'. An example of a negative split is in my question. A positive split would be when the second lap time is slower than the first one. - So maybe it is 'split'!

Comment: I think *splits* works, but the link in my comment implies the *splits* are longer than this.  However that link is more to do with distance/road running than track running. I'm not an expert though.

Comment: Just to try to clear things up a bit, splits can apply to any random portion of an event and start from the starting gun. So in the 10k cross-country ski racing at the Olympics, they reported splits for 1.6k, 5k, and 8.2k, or something like that. The split times were cumulative and used for comparison with different competitors. Lap times, or intervals, are different. They are not cumulative.

Comment: Allright! So I guess that I am looking for the term 'split' here. And that the difference between a split is simply: the difference between a split. Though, why are reporters talking about positive and negative splits?

Comment: @DerkJanSpeelman - Probably not. A "split" is (usually, in my experience) the time to do a part distance, not the difference in time between one part distance and the next. So, in a 4 lap race, after 1 lap you might say "Look at the split! They're on record-breaking pace." And then after the second lap "Oh, the split's not so good this time." When listening to athletics commentary, I've never been sure whether a split after 2 laps is the total time to complete the first two laps, or just the time for the second lap. Dictionary.com hasn't answered this for me.